# Loop To Next Range Using Find VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to code a macro that finds the word (Table 1-1) and then looks for the next word in the document (Table 2-1) and formats Table 1-1 into an actual word table. I have that part figured out and working well.

It is the looping part that I can't seem to get to work. I want it to move onto the next range to find the set of Tables which would be (Table 2-1) to (Table 3-1). I want it to do this for every table in the document until it runs through all of them.

Here is the code:

```
Sub FindTableFormatIt()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String
    Dim tableEach As Table
    Dim i As Long


    For i = 1 To 100
    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range


            If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Table") Then
                Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
                    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Table") Then
                        Set rng3 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
                        ActiveDocument.Range(rng3.Start, rng2.Start).ConvertToTable

                    End If
            End If
    Next i          
End Sub
```

Here is what the word document looks like.

```
Table 1-1
Q1. When there is an election for president do you always vote, almost always vote, vote most of the time, vote some of the time, hardly ever vote, or never vote?

                              Total
                             -------

Total                            600
Always                          87.8
Almost always                    6.0
Most of time                     4.3
Sometimes                        2.0

Table 2-1
Q2. For statistical purposes, what is your age?

                              Total
                             -------

Total                            600
18-34                           21.2
     18-29                      13.5
     30-34                       7.7

35-44                           18.1
     35-39                       8.8
     40-44                       9.4

45-54                           16.4

55-64                           18.6
     55-60                      10.9
     61-64                       7.6

65+                             25.7
Mean                            50.0

Table 3-1
Q3. Gender:
(NET DIF 1 - Percent male minus percent female)

                              Total
                             -------

Total                            600
Male                            48.0
Female                          52.0
NET DIF 1                       -4.0

Table 4-1
Q4. If you had to label yourself, would you say you are a liberal, a moderate or a conservative in your political beliefs?
(NET DIF 1 - Percent Conservative minus percent Liberal)

                              Total
                             -------

Total                            600
Liberal                         28.4
     Very Liberal               12.9
     Somewhat Liberal           15.4

Moderate                        31.1

Conservative                    35.3
     Somewhat Conservative      14.7
     Very Conservative          20.6

DK/Refused                       5.3
NET DIF 1                        7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have a coded solution. This will properly loop and format each text into the proper table range and space them out so that there isn't a table bleeding onto two pages.

```
Sub FindTableFormatIt()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim pagenum As Integer



Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
pagenum = 1



Do Until Not rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="(^13)<Table>", MatchWildcards:=True)
    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)



    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="(^13)<Table>", MatchWildcards:=True) Then
        If rng2.Information(3) > pagenum Then
            Set rng3 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start - 1, rng1.Start - 1)
            rng3.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
            pagenum = rng2.Information(3)
        End If



        ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start, rng2.Start - 1).ConvertToTable
        Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng2.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End)

    Else

        If rng2.Information(3) > pagenum Then
            Set rng3 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start - 1, rng1.Start - 1)
            rng3.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
            pagenum = rng2.Information(3)

        End If



        ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End).ConvertToTable
        Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)

    End If

 Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .InsertAfter Chr(12)
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^13Table"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p^12Table"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "Table*^12"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Characters.Last.Delete
    .Start = .Paragraphs(2).Range.End
    .ConvertToTable vbTab
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So why the downvote??? The code does everything that was asked for!

Comment: I didn't down vote your solution. I did try to use it and can say it didn't do what I needed. It looks like you used the macro recorder to code your solution.

Comment: The code works 100% with the sample data you provided. If it's not working in your actual document, that's only because what you provided doesn't reflect the reality. «It looks like you used the macro recorder to code your solution» If you believe that, you've never used the macro recorder...